# Javascript: how to cancel form submission without return false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form submission code, which does an AJAX call & redirects from there- if match found.

But, somehow, return false is omitted & the form is getting submitted.

I dont want to use return false, & needs to cancel submission for all cases. Is there any jquery method for that?

```
function getLogin()
{       
    //cancel form submission code here


    $username = $('#username').val();
    $password = $('#password').val();
    console.log('Logging- '+$username+' - '+$password);

    callAjaxService($username, $password);  // redirects according to response from this method
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <form action=""  method="get" onSubmit="getLogin();">
```

Actual code is in Jquery-mobile & having issue with `return false;` in the end of the getLogin() function- it cant stop Submitting the form.

Comment: `return false;` is the easiest way to achieve what you want. Just put it after the call to the ajax function. Everything will still work fine.

Comment: You can use `event.preventDefault()`, but why would you _not_ want to `return false`?

Comment: How is getLogin() method getting called?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might not require returning false would be to make make ajax call synchronous rather than asynchronous.  This would ensure that the method returned before getLogin completed.  Such synchronous calls are usually bad practice.  Why is returning false not an option here?

Comment: I used to have onSubmit="return getLogin();" ;it didnt worked either.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the getLogin is bound to a form submit button/link, you could use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
function getLogin(e)
{       
    //cancel form submission code here
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Get rid of `onSubmit="getLogin();"`

```
<form id="uniqueID" action=""  method="get">
```

and then use [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#uniqueID").click(getLogin);
})
```

Comment: How to call the getLogin(); from HTML with event as param?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the `getLogin()` is called?  And Do you have a button like `<input type="submit" onclick="getLogin()">` which submits the form.

If so, add a click handler and implement the code there as below,

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" onclick="getLogin()" id="submit_btn">
```

**JS:**

```
$('#submit_btn').click (function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); //this should stop the form submission.

     getLogin();
});
```

Comment: getLogin(){ } function is within a common js script- which is called from many files, & I dont want to add this $('#submit_btn').click(funct...) to all the page's document.ready(){ }.

Just want to modify getLogin()

Answer (score 1):

i dont know for sure if this work, but this i would try rigging the submit handler:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
  var user = $('#username').val();
  var pw = $('#password').val();
  $.ajax(..., { success: function(data){
    if( data.condition )$('#myform').submit();
    else window.location = 'redirect.html';
  });
  return false;  
});
```

after reading [docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for 10 secs, i noticed, this can be combined with the `preventDefault` mentioned elsewhere:

```
  $('#myform').submit(ev, function(){ 
       ev.preventDefault();
   ...
```

but `return false` should work as well.

Comment: getLogin(){ } function is within a common js script, & dont want to change each document.ready(){} in each page; to add this snippet. Is there a way to catch the event within that getLogin(){ } or send event as parameter from HTML ?

Comment: yes, pass the event to `getLogin(ev)` and/or make the selector of the form a certain convention. or get the form by ascending from the `#username` element, i think `$('#username').form();` ?

Comment: Can u plz elaborate- how to pass the ev from HTML ? onSubmit="getLogin( !! );" ?

Comment: you are misunderstanding me. i wouldn't use the onSubmit. if you are willing to edit that line anyway, give your form a good class name or an id and set up your events via selectors. you can do that in one document.ready in the same file that contains getLogin().

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just set the action-Parameter right?

```
action="javascript:;"
```

BTW: an even better solution would be to set the action-Parameter to this at $(window).load(..).
Why? Because if you want the form to be usable when JS is deactivated it is necessary to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If handler is not returning false, either a logic problem..or more likely an error thrown within handler before code reaches the return

Try using event.preventDefault() before your other code in handler

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLogin()
{
    var e = window.event;
    e.preventDefault();


    $username = ...
    ...

}
```